# Align center differences among browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

What I wanted to achieve was centering a string meanwhile forcing it to the bottom of the container div, but the following produces 3 different outcomes in different browsers.

```
<style>
         #outer {
            position: relative;
            background-color:blue;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
         }

         #inner {
            bottom: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            background-color:red;
         }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <span id="inner">
                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Chrome centers the #inner perfectly.
Firefox start outputting the string **from** the perfect center to the right, so somehow it looks a little shifted, the longer the string, the more obvious to the eye.
IE starts outputting the text from the left.

Is there any workaround for this? Which behaviour complies with the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i think you should give left and right :0 in your css as like this

```
#inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `text-align: center;` on the div#inner, and remove it from the div#outer.

Comment: won't have any effect since inner is an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner should have a negative margin that is 1/2 your element's width.

```
#inner{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    width:500px;
    margin-left:-250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Positioning your inner element vertically centered in combination with absolute positioning is only possible, if you declare a width on it, which only has effect, if it is a non inline-element.

so you need this additional rules:

```
#inner{
   display:inline-block;
   width:<yourWidth>px;
   margin-left:-<yourWidth/2>px;
   left:50%;
}
```

alternatively, you could do the following:

```
#inner{
   display:block;
   left:0;
   text-align:center;
}
```

side note: according to spec 0 may never have a unit, so always write `top:0;` instead of `top:0px;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use jQuery if CSS is going wacky. First hide the content using CSS, then have jQuery center it and unhide it when the content is loaded. Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newWidth = ($('#outer').width() - $('#inner').width()) / 2;
    $('#inner').css({'visibility': 'visible', 'margin-left': newWidth});
});
```

This is untested but should work for any condition.